# Textview - Max Length not working with ellipsize

Tags: android

I am trying to create a textview so that if the number of characters goes above 22, an ellipses " . . ." would appear. However this does not work with maxLength.

[image]

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_postedby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="zz12345678901234567890aaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLength="22"/>
```

How can I get the ellipses to appear while keeping the max digits of 22?

**Here is the full layout:___________________________________________________**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_imagepreview"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_imagepreview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_imagepreview"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_postedby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="zz12345678901234567890aaa"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLength="22"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=" • 18 hours ago"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_postedby"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="zz12345678901234567890aaaaaaaa"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxEms="11"
    />
```

Comment: How does adding maxEms fix the issue? I don't really understand at all...

Answer (score 1):

According to Android Documentation

> If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle.

Your view width is `wrap_content`, that means that unless the text goes to another line, it will fit in the view size.

Unfortunately, this means that you need to replace your string at the 22nd digit with `...` by yourself.

This code might work for you, but I haven't tested it yet.

```
var text = "Text that is longer than 22 digit"
text = text.replaceRange(22, text.length, "...")
```

Another solution is to set the width to a fixed number, but then you will have to measure how long is 22 digits, which is not easy considering that you need to also add the "..." width into the equation as well.

Comment: you can also try this as an extension function:
`fun String.ellipsizeTitle(cutOffLength: Int = 17) = if (this.length-3 <= cutOffLength) this else this.replaceRange(cutOffLength, this.length, "...")`

Answer (score 0):

You missed those lines:

```
android:lines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change width of TextView (vh_fragnotifications_postedby) to 0dp and your problem solved.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_imagepreview"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_imagepreview"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_imagepreview"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_postedby"
    android:layout_width="149dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLength="22"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="zz12345678901234567890aaa"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text=" • 18 hours ago"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_postedby"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body" />


<View
    android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_divider"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"/>
```

Hope this will really help.

Comment: Have you notice only 22 character is showing in your textview.

Comment: yes its displaying only 22 currently in the view, however the text is zz12345678901234567890aaa which is 25 characters. And that should have ellipses

Comment: It is not showing as ellipses text because it have enough space to show it

Comment: Fixed the width of textView (18 hours) and then it will show in ellipses format

Comment: I'm using a constraint layout and I want to see if theirs a solution without requiring a nested linearlayout. Also added my full layout in the Edit Above

Comment: I already stated the issue with 0dp for layout width in response to @Sunny. It causes an empty space when the length of the string is short. https://i.imgur.com/xjyPLzn.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to fix the length size **22**. I will suggest you make it a single line Like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_postedby"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="zz12345678901234567890aaaaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_body"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/vh_fragnotifications_dateposted"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

The reason for not using the **android:maxLength** is that when you have space on left side of the view it will not showing **...** in the end. It will be  the only 22 character nothing else.

Comment: yes I have already tried changing the width to 0dp to fix the issue however that causes an empty space when the length of the string is short. https://i.imgur.com/xjyPLzn.png